# how to bult N Type category tree with php?

Tags: php

we have this table "Categoris"

```
------------------------------------
| ID  |parent.id | Category Name   |
|  1  |    0     |  php            |
|  2  |    1     |  Jquery         |
|  3  |    2     |  Java script    |
|  4  |    2     |  HTML           | 
|  5  |    4     |  CSS            |
|  6  |    1     |  word Press     |
|  7  |    3     |  DOM            |
```

Output should be

```
PHP->Jquery
   ->wordpres
Jquery->java Script
      ->HTML
Java Script->DOM
HTML-> CSS
Word Press
DOM
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at PEAR's [Tree package](http://pear.php.net/package/Tree).